# ILLEGAL errors using meteor build on tutorial

Tags: macos, meteor, build

I am following the tutorial for [creating a Meteor app](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) and would like to deploy it locally on a machine running Mac OS 10.8.5. The build is failing, due to errors perceived in some of the test and example files provided by certain node_modules. Here is the output:

```
$ meteor build osx --architecture os.osx.x86_64 --directory

WARNING: The output directory is under your source tree.

Errors prevented bundling:                    
While building the application:               

build/bundle/programs/server/npm/webapp/node_modules/connect/node_modules/multiparty/examples/azureblobstorage.js:38:2:
Unexpected token )

build/bundle/programs/server/npm/webapp/node_modules/useragent/node_modules/lru-cache/test/memory-leak.js:1:15:
Unexpected token ILLEGAL

build/bundle/programs/server/npm/logging/node_modules/cli-color/test/__playground/throbber.formatted.js:1:15:
Unexpected token ILLEGAL

build/bundle/programs/server/npm/logging/node_modules/cli-color/test/__playground/throbber.js:1:15:
Unexpected token ILLEGAL

build/bundle/programs/server/npm/webapp/node_modules/useragent/bin/testfiles.js:1:15:
Unexpected token ILLEGAL

build/bundle/programs/server/npm/webapp/node_modules/useragent/bin/update.js:1:15:
Unexpected token ILLEGAL
build/bundle/programs/web.browser/head.html:1: bad formatting in HTML template
```

I understand that I can deploy to Meteor's own servers, but my purpose is to discover how to deploy a project to my own server, so that I can judge how smooth the process is going to be. Eventually, I want to use a RedHat server, but for now I prefer to test locally.

One solution would be to delete the unneeded test and example files, but it appears that these are downloaded automatically during the build process.

What can you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.build` (or anything hidden) for your build directory or move it outside your project directory tree. It can be done by providing the right value fro `--directory` option. Otherwise meteor will put into bundle the build itself, which results in an infinite recursion.